# Output is not generated AudioConverterFillComplexBuffer to convert from AAC to PCM?

Tags: ios, iphone, core-audio, codec

Hi I am trying to convert AAC buffer to PCM using AudioConverterFillComplexBuffer..Here is my code

```
 -(void)initDecoder{
         AudioStreamBasicDescription outAudioStreamBasicDescription;
        outAudioStreamBasicDescription.mSampleRate = 44100.0;
        outAudioStreamBasicDescription.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
        outAudioStreamBasicDescription.mFormatFlags = 0xc;
        outAudioStreamBasicDescription.mBytesPerPacket = 2;
        outAudioStreamBasicDescription.mFramesPerPacket = 1;
        outAudioStreamBasicDescription.mBytesPerFrame = 2;
        outAudioStreamBasicDescription.mChannelsPerFrame = 1;
        outAudioStreamBasicDescription.mBitsPerChannel = 16;

        AudioStreamBasicDescription inAudioStreamBasicDescription;

        inAudioStreamBasicDescription.mSampleRate = 44100;
        inAudioStreamBasicDescription.mFormatID = kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC;
        inAudioStreamBasicDescription.mFormatFlags = kMPEG4Object_AAC_SSR;
        inAudioStreamBasicDescription.mBytesPerPacket = 0;
        inAudioStreamBasicDescription.mFramesPerPacket = 1024;
        inAudioStreamBasicDescription.mBytesPerFrame = 0;
        inAudioStreamBasicDescription.mChannelsPerFrame = 1;
        inAudioStreamBasicDescription.mBitsPerChannel = 0;
        inAudioStreamBasicDescription.mReserved = 0;


        AudioClassDescription audioClassDescription;
        memset(&audioClassDescription, 0, sizeof(audioClassDescription));


        audioClassDescription.mManufacturer = kAppleSoftwareAudioCodecManufacturer;
        audioClassDescription.mSubType = outAudioStreamBasicDescription.mFormatID;
        audioClassDescription.mType = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
        NSAssert(audioClassDescription.mSubType == outAudioStreamBasicDescription.mFormatID && audioClassDescription.mManufacturer == kAppleSoftwareAudioCodecManufacturer, nil);


        NSAssert(AudioConverterNewSpecific(&inAudioStreamBasicDescription, &outAudioStreamBasicDescription, 1, &audioClassDescription, &audioConverterDecode) == 0, nil);

     }

    OSStatus inInputDataProc(AudioConverterRef inAudioConverter, UInt32 *ioNumberDataPackets, AudioBufferList *ioData, AudioStreamPacketDescription **outDataPacketDescription, void *inUserData)
    {
        AudioBufferList audioBufferList = *(AudioBufferList *)inUserData;

        ioData->mBuffers[0].mData = audioBufferList.mBuffers[0].mData;
        ioData->mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize = audioBufferList.mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize;

        return  noErr;
    }

    -(void)decodeSample:(AudioBufferList)inAaudioBufferList{
        //inAaudioBufferList is the AAC buffer

        if (!audioConverterDecode) {

            [self initDecoder];
        }

         NSAssert(inAaudioBufferList.mNumberBuffers == 1, nil);

        uint32_t bufferSize = 1024*2;//inAaudioBufferList.mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize;
        uint8_t *buffer = (uint8_t *)malloc(1024*2);
        memset(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        AudioBufferList outAudioBufferList;
        outAudioBufferList.mNumberBuffers = 1;
        outAudioBufferList.mBuffers[0].mNumberChannels = 1;
        outAudioBufferList.mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize = bufferSize;
        outAudioBufferList.mBuffers[0].mData = buffer;

        UInt32 ioOutputDataPacketSize = bufferSize;


       OSStatus ret = AudioConverterFillComplexBuffer(audioConverterDecode, inInputDataProc, &inAaudioBufferList, &ioOutputDataPacketSize, &outAudioBufferList, NULL) ;//== 0, nil);

        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:outAudioBufferList.mBuffers[0].mData length:outAudioBufferList.mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize];
        DLog(@"Rev Size = %d",(unsigned int)outAudioBufferList.mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize);
        free(buffer);

    }
```

The decoded output length is zero and the OSStatus code for AudioConverterFillComplexBuffer is 561015652

So what could be wrong..?

Comment: There is my sample how to decode AAC to PCM
http://stackoverflow.com/a/39958181/6250364

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a shot in the dark and you probably already found the solution to this but I believe you need to change this
     `UInt32 ioOutputDataPacketSize = bufferSize;`
to this

```
UInt32 ioOutputDataPacketSize = bufferSize/2;
```

Personally for me I do this in the inInputDataProc method and always sent

```
UInt32 ioOutputDataPacketSize = 1;
```

into the AudioConverterFillComplexBuffer method and then set it within the inInputDataProc like this.

```
UInt32 maxPackets = audioBufferList.mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize / 2;
*ioNumberDataPackets = maxPackets;
```

Hope this helps.