# What files are supported in Speech Framework iOS 10

Tags: ios, speech-to-text

I have tried to search Apple's document, but no luck.

In particular, is `.aac` supported?

Answer (score 0):

I found that `.aac` is not supported for speech recognition.

Instead, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39958181/3838949) is a potential way to convert `.aac` to PCM